# Using Ansible inventory group hostname in template

Tags: ansible, kibana

I'm trying to use the [geerlingguy.kibana](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-kibana) role to install Kibana with Ansible 2.2.1.0. I made a playbook that looks like the following. My inventory has a group like this:

```
[kibana_node]
myHostname
```

I setup a variable for the node group in case I want to customize it on the command-line. (kibana_node_group). I wanted to dynamically pull the kibana node value from the inventory to be used by the geerlingguy.kibana role, but the template isn't working as I expected. I found a syntax that works in a debug statement, but it doesn't work in the template code for the config file.

Playbook:

```
- hosts: "{{ kibana_node_group }}"

  pre_tasks:

  - debug:
      var: "groups.{{ kibana_node_group }}[0]"

  roles:
      - geerlingguy.kibana

  vars:
      kibana_node_group: kibana_node
      kibana_server_host: "groups.{{ kibana_node_group }}[0]"
```

In the geerlingguy.kibana role, he has this template code to setup the config file:

```
# The host to bind the server to.
server.host: {{ kibana_server_host }}
```

When I run this playbook, this is what gets put in the config file:

```
server.host: groups.kibana_node[0]
```

I expected to see "myHostname" like the debug output shows, but that didn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kibana_server_host: groups.{{ kibana_node_group }}[0]` is python equivalent for `"groups." + kibana_node_group + "[0]"`, where `groups.` and `[0]` are just strings.

Use `kibana_server_host: "{{ groups[kibana_node_group][0] }}"` instead